# Why I can't configure OAuth 2.0 using Python?

Tags: python, json, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I was trying to get my uploading YouTube video software to work using this guide/code:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

I installed & setup everything that is requiered. Also, I made new project, changed YouTube Data API v3's state to ON, got my credentials, entered them to client_secrets.json (also tried downloading one via button that google provided, btw. I renamed downloaded one to client_secrets.json manually, so that's not problem) but when I try to upload something I get this error:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%>c:/Python27/python.exe C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\youtube_uploader\up
load.py --file=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\youtube_uploader\test_klip\test.mp4 --tit
le=Test upload

WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

     C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\youtube_uploader\clientinfo.json

with information from the APIs Console
https://code.google.com/apis/console#access

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
```

Is there anything I missed or done wrong? If so, please help me to get this to work.

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S. I tried making and using both web/installed type of credentials but none of them work.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue.